# Подбор данных для NULL значений в реляционной базе данных

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

У меня задача: в реляционной базе данных найти возможные значения для NULL полей на основе существующих данных.

Например, такая таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В идеале нужно чтобы в SELECT запросе вместо NULL выдавало список из возможных вариантов отцов для Майкла, Франца и Барта.
Например, результаты для 
*SELECT character, father FROM table:*

Джон - Майкл

Майкл - [Франц, Барт]

Франц - [Майкл, Барт, Джон]

Барт - [Джон, Майкл, Франц]

То есть, хоть в базе и NULL, но на запрос выдало массив возможных вариантов из тех персонажей, что есть в базе.

Возможно ли подобное в SQL Server? Может с применением Data Mining. Каким вообще образом подобное можно решить?

Comment: сформулируйте вопрос нормально. Приведите пример исходных данных и желаемый результат. Что за все возможные? кто считается возможным, откуда их выбирать? Хорошо что вы сами представляете что вы хотите найти, но попробуйте вразумительно и остальным это объяснить на нормальных примерах с нормальны описанием задачи.

Comment: обновил вопрос, добавил ожидаемый результат

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под массивом? запрос возвращает набор строк. например может вернуть две строки `Майкл - Франц` и `Майкл - Барт`. Массива запрос вернуть не может. Но возможна конкатенация имен в строку, вида `Майкл - "Франц, Барт"`. какой из вариантов вам нужен?

Answer (score 0):

```
select person,coalesce(father,replace((select person as 'data()' 
from t t1 where t.father is null and person<>t.person 
and person not in(select person from t t2 where t2.father=t.person)
for xml path('')),' ',', ')) father from t
```

father = отец

person = персона

Comment: Джон не может быть отцом Майкла, потому что является сыном.

Comment: Согласен. Подлатал.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        character,
        father
    FROM characters)
SELECT
    t1.character,
    father = ISNULL(t1.father, SUBSTRING(t3.father,1,LEN(t3.father)-1))
FROM cte AS t1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
        t2.character + ',' AS 'data()'
    FROM cte t2
    WHERE t1.father IS NULL
        AND t1.character NOT IN (t2.character, ISNULL(t2.father,''))
    FOR XML PATH('')
            ) AS t3(father);
```